# Current User's ID as Default Attribute in QGIS (QField)

Tags: qgis, qfield, user-interface

I have a QGIS project running on QField that allows the user to draw points/lines and assign attributes to them. As soon as the point/line is drawn, an attribute mask pops up where all the attributes and photos are filled in. Since this QField project is used by many users (each having an unique ID), it also asks for the ID of the user.

**Is there a way to define the user's ID as *current* default value, so that the current user doesn't always need to select their ID in the dropdown?**

Also, all the users use the same tablet at different times.

Answer (score 1):

There are the variables `user_account_name` and `user_full_name` which access you Windows-"ID". These can be set as preset values for any field of the fitting type of a layer, thus entering the value automatically when a feature is created.

Comment: All the users use the same tablet with the same project on it at different times. So, they would have the same ID. Is there a way to define an ID as soon as a different user starts editing the project?

Comment: But they have different user names & passwords?

Comment: At the moment, the project simply asks for a general password. I will try to set different passwords for each user. Thx for the idea!

Comment: `user_account_name` refers to the OS-user.

Answer (score 0):

`@project_author` The project author, taken from project metadata.This ends up being the persons name from QField account instead of a device ID or OS ID. Works for multiple users on different devices.

Since you have multiple users using the same account, you might try a Value Map so the user can select their ID instead of typing it in each time.